# Angular Routing Problem with Fuse admin and user

Tags: angular, fuse

I have problem with navigating route for admin and user only ( have limitation than admin )

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>

const routes: Route[] = [
    {path: '', pathMatch : 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},

    {path: 'signed-in-redirect', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'admin/dashboard'},
    {path: 'admin-signed-in-redirect', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'admin/dashboard'},
    {path: 'user-signed-in-redirect', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'user/dashboard'},
    {
        path: '',
        component  : LayoutComponent,
        data: {
            layout: 'empty'
        },
        children   : [
            {path: '', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/landing/home/home.module').then(m => m.LandingHomeModule)},
        ]
    },
   

];


if (environment.allowSignUp) {
    routes.push(
        {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [NoAuthGuard],
            canActivateChild: [NoAuthGuard],
            component: LayoutComponent,
            data: {
                layout: 'empty'
            },
            children: [
                {path: 'confirmation-required', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/confirmation-required/confirmation-required.module').then(m => m.AuthConfirmationRequiredModule)},
                {path: 'forgot-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.AuthForgotPasswordModule)},
                {path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/reset-password/reset-password.module').then(m => m.AuthResetPasswordModule)},
                {path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInModule)},
                {path: 'sign-in-transition', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in-transition/sign-in-transition.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInTransitionModule)},
                {path: 'sign-up', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-up/sign-up.module').then(m => m.AuthSignUpModule)},
                {path: 'sign-up-confirmation', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-up-confirmation/sign-up-confirmation.module').then(m => m.AuthSignUpConfirmationModule)},
            ]
        }
    );
}
else {
    routes.push(
        {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [NoAuthGuard],
            canActivateChild: [NoAuthGuard],
            component: LayoutComponent,
            data: {
                layout: 'empty'
            },
            children: [
                {path: 'confirmation-required', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/confirmation-required/confirmation-required.module').then(m => m.AuthConfirmationRequiredModule)},
                {path: 'forgot-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.AuthForgotPasswordModule)},
                {path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/reset-password/reset-password.module').then(m => m.AuthResetPasswordModule)},
                {path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInModule)},
                {path: 'sign-in-transition', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in-transition/sign-in-transition.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInTransitionModule)},
            ]
        }
    );
}

routes.push(
    {
        path: 'admin',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        component: LayoutComponent,
        data: {
            layout: 'empty'
        },
        children: [
            {path: 'admin/dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/dashboards/analytics/analytics.module').then(m => m.AnalyticsModule)},
            {path: 'user/dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/user/dashboard/user-analytics.module').then(m => m.UserAnalyticsModule)},
            {path: 'solarmanagement/:id', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/userassigned/userassigned.module').then(m => m.UserassignedModule)},
            {path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule)},
            {path: 'user/settings', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/dashboards/pages/settings/settingsuser.module').then(m => m.SettingsUserModule)},
            {path: 'usergroup', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/usergroup/usergroup.module').then(m => m.UsergroupModule)},
            {path: 'solarmanagement', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/solarmanagement/solarmanagement.module').then(m => m.SolarmanagementModule)},
            {path: '404-not-found', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/error/error-404/error-404.module').then(m => m.Error404Module)},
            {path: '**', redirectTo: '404-not-found'},
            {path: 'sign-out', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-out/sign-out.module').then(m => m.AuthSignOutModule)},
            {path: 'unlock-session', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/unlock-session/unlock-session.module').then(m => m.AuthUnlockSessionModule)}
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component  : LayoutComponent,
        data: {
            layout: 'empty'
        },
        children   : [
            {path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/landing/home/home.module').then(m => m.LandingHomeModule)},
            {path: 'sign-out', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-out/sign-out.module').then(m => m.AuthSignOutModule)},
            {path: 'unlock-session', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/unlock-session/unlock-session.module').then(m => m.AuthUnlockSessionModule)},
            {path: 'confirmation-required', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/confirmation-required/confirmation-required.module').then(m => m.AuthConfirmationRequiredModule)},
                {path: 'forgot-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.AuthForgotPasswordModule)},
                {path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/reset-password/reset-password.module').then(m => m.AuthResetPasswordModule)},
                {path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInModule)},
                {path: 'sign-in-transition', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in-transition/sign-in-transition.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInTransitionModule)},
        ]
    },

    {
        path       : 'user',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        component  : LayoutComponent,
        resolve    : {
            initialData: InitialDataResolver,
        },
        children   : [

            {path: 'user/dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/user/dashboard/user-analytics.module').then(m => m.UserAnalyticsModule)},
            {path: 'solarmanagement/:id', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/userassigned/userassigned.module').then(m => m.UserassignedModule)},
            {path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule)},
            {path: 'user/settings', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/dashboards/pages/settings/settingsuser.module').then(m => m.SettingsUserModule)},
            {path: 'usergroup', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/usergroup/usergroup.module').then(m => m.UsergroupModule)},
            {path: 'solarmanagement', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/solarmanagement/solarmanagement.module').then(m => m.SolarmanagementModule)},
            {path: '404-not-found', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/pages/error/error-404/error-404.module').then(m => m.Error404Module)},
            {path: '**', redirectTo: '404-not-found'},
            
        ]
    }
)
```

how to routing the right way to put admin only placement and user only placement. All I do when login is going to user and not even admin got the placement. When login admin must be admin routing and if user login must be user routing only.

Answer (score 0):

After a while with similar problem, I find out that the problem is when you change route fuse config get changed also but the config.layout is not proberly set so I had to handle this issue

in config.service.ts

```
  !isString(value?.layout)?value.layout = this._config.getValue()?.layout : ''
```

I also added a condition to this code in ngOnInit in layout.component.ts

```
 // Subscribe to config changes
    this._fuseConfigService.config$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((config: FuseConfig) => {
            // Store the config
            if(config?.layout){
                this.config = config;
            }else if(config){
                this.config = {...config,layout:"classy"};
            }
            // Update the layout
            this._updateLayout();
        });
```